# For Each loop only fires once

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am making a connect four game to learn some VBA.

I have an unbound form with buttons for the game pieces (tokens). An option group to pick which column to drop the token. A textbox (hidden) that represents which row the token is to be dropped on.

If I manually input a number in the textbox then hit the Drop Button it works as intended. Fills in the token and adds one to the correct textbox.

Example:
Put a 1 in to txtR1 hit drop button.
Token is filled in and txtR1 now shows 2, hit the drop button again and nothing. If I manually put a 2 in txtR1 then it works as intended.

Is the txtbox not updated when it shows it is?

I arranged the code str and row in the if statement and tried adding save in there and refresh.

```vb
Private Sub drop()
    
    Dim Token As Control
    Dim Row As Control
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim str As String
    
    c = Me.frmCol
    str = "txtR" & c
    Set Row = Me(str)
    r = Row
    
    For Each Token In Controls
    
        If InStr(Token.Tag, "C" & c) Then
    
            If Right(Token.name, 1) = Row Then
            
                Token.BackStyle = 1
                Token.BackColor = vbBlue
                Row = r + 1
                Exit Sub
                
            End If
    
        End If
        
    Next Token
    
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: `Row = r + 1` maybe this should be `Row = Row + 1`?

Comment: @dwirony That has the same result. The txtbox updates as should.

Comment: This is a first for me - asking for an image. Can you edit question to show image of form?

Comment: @June7 Uploaded img

Comment: `Row` is dim'd as a control. `r` is dim'd as an integer. You then do `r=Row`... that seems odd. `r=c` would make much more sense here.  When you do something like `<some scalar variable>=<object>` you get the default property of the object. It seems very unlikely that the default property of an object of type `control` is the row number you are after (the value of `c`). Instead you are probably getting the index of the control in `Me` which doesn't seem like a safe thing to base code off of.

Comment: Later, in your loop you do `Row = r + 1` which is setting `Row`, a `Control` object, to an integer... Not a control. This should be `Set Row=Me("txtR" & r + 1)` or similar.

Comment: @JNevill I am still learning all of this. My my crazy logic is thinking is that the when the frmCol (c)  picks the correct txtR(1-7) box. The txtR box has the row number(r)(1-6) then picks the correct btn(1-6) to fill in. then adds 1 to the txtR box for the next row. I'm sure this is not the typical way the pros would go about this. Just trying to learn.

Comment: Well I feel dumb now. I found out where i went wrong. my 2nd if statement was wrong  it had `= row` when I needed `=r`. Thank you guys for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider alternative that uses numeric suffix control naming without looping to set token colors but uses loop to reset the game:

```
Private Sub optDrop_Click()
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
c = Me.optDrop
r = Me("tbx" & c) + 1
If Me("tbx" & c) = 6 Then
    MsgBox "This column is full. Pick another."
Else
    Me("box" & c & r).BackColor = IIf(Me.tbxPlayer = "Player 1", vbCyan, vbMagenta)
    Me("tbx" & c) = Me("tbx" & c) + 1
    Me.tbxPlayer = IIf(Me.tbxPlayer = "Player 1", "Player 2", "Player 1")
    Me.tbxPlayer.BackColor = IIf(Me.tbxPlayer = "Player 1", vbCyan, vbMagenta)
End If
Me.optDrop = 0
End Sub

Private Sub btnReset_Click()
Dim c As Integer, r As Integer
Me.tbxPlayer = "Player 1"
Me.tbxPlayer.BackColor = vbCyan
For c = 1 To 7
    For r = 1 To 6
        Me("box" & c & r).BackColor = vbWhite
    Next
    Me("tbx" & c) = 0
Next
End Sub
```

Rectangle controls are used for tokens and optDrop is option group frame control.

Haven't figured out code to check for 4 in a row and declare winner. Probably beyond my ability and interest.

BONUS: If you want to watch the tokens 'dropping', consider:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lngMilliSeconds As Long)

Private Sub optDrop_Click()
Dim r As Integer, c As Integer, x As Integer, dteD As Date
c = Me.optDrop
r = Me("tbx" & c) + 1
If Me("tbx" & c) = 6 Then
    MsgBox "This column is full. Pick another."
Else
    For x = 6 To r Step -1
        Me("box" & c & x).BackColor = IIf(Me.tbxPlayer = "Player 1", vbCyan, vbMagenta)
        dteD = Now()
        Do
            Sleep 300
            DoEvents
        Loop Until Now >= dteD
        Me("box" & c & x).BackColor = vbWhite
    Next
    Me("box" & c & r).BackColor = IIf(Me.tbxPlayer = "Player 1", vbCyan, vbMagenta)
    Me("tbx" & c) = Me("tbx" & c) + 1
    Me.tbxPlayer = IIf(Me.tbxPlayer = "Player 1", "Player 2", "Player 1")
    Me.tbxPlayer.BackColor = IIf(Me.tbxPlayer = "Player 1", vbCyan, vbMagenta)
End If
Me.optDrop = 0
End Sub
```

I moved toggle buttons to top of columns so get more of a feel of 'dropping' tokens.

Comment: This looks great. Was going to work on the second player part but see that is covered here. So far in this journey of learning all this I have found out to write a little bit of code then test it to death before adding more haha. For some reason I been under the impression that everything has to be dim'd even the controls. But i see thats not the case. Thank you. I will let ya know how it goes tomorrow.

Comment: This work just as expected. Its funny cause I had all the stuff in place as far as the numeric suffix. Just my limited knowledge on the subject tried to make it harder than it was. As far as win condition I know that is beyond my ability. Guess the ole eye will do for now. One day I will figure it out. Thanks again for taking the time to help out.

Comment: @Digitalhangover, see revised answer.

Comment: Thats a really cool trick!!! Looks great and works great. You have really went above and beyond and I can't thank you enough. I learned some stuff and have another game in my small but growing collection. At the end of the day thats what is all about. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake. Second If statement was wrong here is the corrected code if anyone ever needs it. Want to again say thank you for the people that was helping me.

```
Private Sub drop()

Dim Token As Control
Dim Row As Control
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim str As String

c = Me.frmCol
str = "txtR" & c
Set Row = Me(str)
r = Row

For Each Token In Controls

    If InStr(Token.Tag, "C" & c) Then

        If Right(Token.name, 1) = r Then
        
            Token.BackStyle = 1
            Token.BackColor = vbBlue
            Row = r + 1
            Exit Sub
            
        End If

    End If
    
Next Token

End Sub
```